# Is the area of a triangle a function of its perimeter?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've already knew how to express the area of an equilateral triangle as a function of its perimeter, but I don't know how to do it for any triangle. But this is a problem in George Simmons's book "Calculus with Analytic Geometry".  Does someone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

A triangle with sides 1,1 and 2 has perimeter 4 and area =0. A triangle with sides all equal to  4/3 has the same perimeter and positive area. Ergo the area is not a function of the perimeter (it is if you restrict to equilateral or other special families)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The zero area triangle is really interesting! Thanks.